# angular 6 override css with condition

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

I used `ng-select` in my project, i removed the cross clear icon using `[clearable]="false"`, and i removed also the clear icon for each item by overriding the `ng-value-icon` class

```
:host ::ng-deep .ng-value-icon {
    display: none !important;
}
```

i want to apply the css with condition

```
  constructor() {
    if(this.result === "ok") {
      //apply the css
    }
  }
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-ogsstk?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

This part of the template (from your Stackblitz) wich decides over the class `custom` relates to a scope var named `step`:

```
   [class.custom]="step === 'step1'"
```

So, use it:

```ts
  step: 'step1'|'not-step1' = 'not-step1';

  constructor() {
    if(this.result === "ok") {
      this.step = "step1";
    }
  }
```

or you change  the condition in the template into

```
   [class.custom]='result === "ok"'
```

Or, most likely better than this css-toggle, you can use`*ngIf`

```
  *ngIf="result === 'ok'"
```

.